# jQuery getting NaN error when trying to set border color (but it works?)

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, colors, border

I'm changing the border color of an object via an animation:

```
    $listItem.siblings('li').andSelf().find('img').animate({ 
            borderTopColor: defaultThumbBorderColor,
            borderBottomColor: defaultThumbBorderColor,
            borderLeftColor: defaultThumbBorderColor,
            borderRightColor: defaultThumbBorderColor
          }, 500 );
```

In Firefox, this works. However, I get this error in the console log:

> Warning: Expected number or percentage in rgb() but found 'NaN'.  Error in parsing value for 'border-bottom-color'.  Declaration dropped.

It seems as if jQuery wants a number for those properties. But even though I'm passing in a string ('red', for instance) it works, but logs that error.

Any idea why?

Bonus question: I can't seem to apply all four border colors with one line via 'borderColor' or 'border-color'. Is the only way to do that as above where you set the individual color of each of the four sides? The problem I run into with the above is that it usually works. But once in a while it'll not animate one of the four borders on a seemingly random item in the array. So, an example scenario: if I have 20 items, it'll animate all four borders on 18 of the items, then 3 of the borders on 2 of them. If it matters, I'm attaching the border to an image. Perhaps that's the culprit? I'll do some testing...

Well, it's not an issue if it specifically being an image. I appears to maybe be a performance glitch (maybe browser? Maybe jQuery?)

If I have a group of elements that I need to change all 4 border colors on at once, most of the time it works, but maybe 1 our of 3 times, 1 or two out of the 20 or so elements will only animate 3 of their borders rather than all four.

At this point, I think I just have to pad the divs and use a background color instead.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using the official jQuery animate to color plugin. If you check it's source you can see that it overrides following properties:

```
// We override the animation for all of these color styles
jQuery.each(['backgroundColor', 'borderBottomColor', 'borderLeftColor', 'borderRightColor', 'borderTopColor', 'color', 'outlineColor'])
```

This explains why borderColor doesn't animate all the borders to the specified color.

Speaking about NaN problem, I think it is a bug. I had the same problem, when I was trying to animate about 30 objects simultaneously to a specific background color. Some animations were just stopping randomly. So workaround with padding-and-background might not work.

Comment: I'm using jQuery UI's built-in color animating (AFAIK, this is a newer addition). I ended up forgoing border animations, padded the box, and animated the background. This gave me consistent visual in terms of it appearing to be a border on all 4 sides. However, it would still randomly 'forget' to animate one particular element now and again. As such, I have a fail safe where after animating, I just over-ride the css and 'snap' it into color if need be. Not perfect, but seems to work. It does appear there are performance issues when animating large numbers of elements at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there was a bug in the jQuery UI color animations plugin which is now fixed. (https://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4251)

And here are the two lines they they changed.

https://dev.jqueryui.com/changeset/3269

I added the above changes to the plugin and haven't had any problems with it since.